# How can I order the following functions such that if $f$ is left of $g$ , then $f=O(g)$ as $x$ goes to $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

Order the following functions $x$, $e^x$, $\ln x$, $x^2$, $x^3$ from left to right such that 
$f$ is to the left of $g$ if $f=O(g)$ as $x$ goes to $0$.

$f=O(g)$ means that limit of $f/g$ as $x$ goes to $0$ is equal to some constant.

However, I can not find out any combination of $f$ and $g$ such that limit of $f/g$ is equal to some constant $C$ as $x$ goes to $0$.

Any idea please

Comment: $f=O(g)$ means that there exists some constant $C$ such that $|f|\le C|g|.$ This doesn't mean that the limit of $f/g$ is a constant.

Comment: In my book, saying that  |f|≤C|g| is equivalent to saying that limit of f/g as x goes to 0 is some constant, though

Comment: Note that $\sin(1/x)=O(1).$ However $\lim_{x\to 0}\sin (1/x)$ doesn't exist. Are you making a confusion with $f=o(g)?$

Comment: What about we have sequence xn and yn such xn=O(yn) ?

Comment: Does that mean that limit of xn/yn  is some constant?

Comment: No. Consider $x_n=(-1)^n$ and $y_n=1.$ The limit $x_n/y_n$ doesn't exist. However $x_n=O(y_n).$

Comment: Let me insist: if the limit of $f/g$ is zero we write $f=o(g).$

Comment: But if limit of f/g is some constant, then can we say that f=O(g) ?

Comment: In such a case the answer is yes.